# SQL column type

Tags: sql-server, cakephp

I am trying to take whereTerm which currently has no type listed in the view in  SQL management when i hover over it and pass it into a stored procedure. well here is the issue it says that **Cannot convert value of type `array` to integer**.

I cannot change the SQL view and was wondering what the proper type is for a column when you hover over it, all it says is COLUMN: whereTerm and that is it. above that is another column named COLUMN: schoolYear - varchar(9). ok so that one has varchar as a type great so what is the type of whereTerm......is there a way to further look the type up or does that column just not have one any help would be appreciated.

```
                 @whereTerm=:whereTerm,
            ',
            [
                'whereTerm' => ['whereTerm'],
            ],
            [
                'whereTerm' => 'integer',
            ]
            )
```

Comment: All view columns have a name and a well defined type in SQL Server. What you are saying is impossible.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. As posted your question makes no sense. But all is not lost. You can edit your question and add some information so others know what you are asking. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good place to start.

Comment: I edited my post to further make since on the issue i am having

Comment: That update did nothing in making this clear. A view MUST have a name for every column or it will not compile. The more I read the question the less clear it becomes. You run the risk of this question receiving downvotes and being closed unless you make it clear.

Comment: Right click the view in SSMS, and script view > as create > to a new window, and find what table/column it references.  Then expand that table schema to find the data type -- if its not showing in SSMS when you hover over the code, that could be because intellisense needs refreshing (CTRL-SHIFT-R) or *maybe* its a custom data type?  You really need to expand on this...

Comment: Every single column MUST have a datatype. There is no exception here. If I understand your question you want to know what datatype a column in a view has?

Comment: Yes i want to know what the datatype in my view is for whereTerm. after sifting through the properties it appears that even there the data type is blank. After looking at the script which i am not to familiar with view it appears nothing is shown errrrr.